# Jest on promises: triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */)

Tags: jestjs, es6-promise

I'm getting this error while running ALL tests (when I the only test directly that load the function involved, there's no error)

```
node:internal/process/promises:246
      triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
      ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block,
or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason
"Error: Ha ocurrido un error, por favor intente de nuevo más tarde".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

The block of code of the function that is generating the error is like this:

```
async getMonthRequests(rut, month) {
  try {
    // some code, in the test I'm testing that it fails
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject('Ha ocurrido un error, por favor intente de nuevo más tarde');
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check the host and port of amqp server while creating connection.

```
amqp://localhost:5672
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).